# MySQL commands not working in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I am able to create databases and tables using the User Interface in phpMyAdmin , but when I do the same using MySQL commands , It does not work. I get this error :

SQL query:

DROP DATABASE 'alphacrm' 
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''alphacrm'' at line 1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use  quote

```
DROP DATABASE alphacrm;
```

my sql object don't need  quotes  eventually use backtics for  reversed  word and compite named  eg:

```
 `my obj`
```

Comment: Thanks , it worked! May god bless you .. and apologies for asking such a silly question .. i am really new to this, tutorials did it using the quotes.